# How do I access a child node in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [React Modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal).

I'm doing something like this:

```
React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <ReactModal
            isOpen={true}
            >{content}</ReactModal>
  }
});
```

Now `{content}` might have an input field inside. I know I can't use `ref` in this case. If I use `getDOMNode`, that can get me the wrapper, but I don't know of an easy way to find a child by class name. Am I supposed to use native code there?

Comment: where does `content` come from ?

Comment: why you want to have access to it? Can't you pass to it props?

Comment: Content is a string of markup coming thru props. The content just being a string is what's throwing me off. I am considering just rewriting how I'm doing this altogether :)

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why a container component would need to know about its children like this.  Can you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about it more and I realize i just need to take advantage of state more. I am transitioning from non-react to React, so slowly realizing how to shift from one paradigm to the other.

Comment: I'd argue that you would actually want to take advantage of `props` more.  Using `state` for each of your components might seem like a good idea at first, but it can quickly turn your codebase into an unintelligible mess.  It has bitten me in the past.

Comment: Yeah I think the problem I had is that I was trying to make this modal work similar to fancybox, just blind opening based on a click - not caring where click came from. However I really need to add `<ReactModal>` next to every place I want a Modal to trigger for proper behavior here.

Comment: Well not *everywhere* but I need to be conscious of it in more places.

Comment: Yeah and then iterate thru them, but I was hoping for something eaiser, however I am gonna write a better answer below essentially saying my question means I'm doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

React components are js objects only. In worst case if you want to access the child you can print the component in your browser console and expand it. You can see the child components, from there also you can access refs and all.